# Issue when trying to run the Sagemaker abalone pipeline example

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When I try and run this line:
`from sagemaker.workflow.steps import ProcessingStep`

I get an error:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'trim_request_dict' from 'sagemaker.workflow.utilities' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/utilities.py)`

I'm unsure of how to fix this, since I have Sagemaker fully updated, how else can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm you are using the latest SDK version here: https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker/#history